# strange behaviour of jquery 'click' event

Tags: jquery

I had an anchor tag

```
<li><a href="#" class="institution">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="department">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="branch">Click me</a></li>
```

i wanted to execute some code by clicking on the anchor tag.so i used

```
$('a').click(function(){
    //do something..
});
```

but it did not work out. So I used

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    //do something..
});
```

also i used

```
$('a').bind('click',function(){
    //do something..
});
```

but they did not work either. what worked for me was

```
$('a').live('click',function(){
    //do something..
});
```

why is this so..when all of them are supposed to show same behaviour.

Comment: are you sure that jquery is loaded? it should work as works here: http://jsfiddle.net/kMSHv/

Comment: i had other jquery codes which were running .. jquery was cent percent loaded..even this query workedd but only by using live

Comment: No, they are not supposed to have the same behavior. Re-read my answer, `.click` and `.bind` don't delegate -- they are bound to the current elements in the page only when the binding is executed. `.live`, in the other hand, will match any `a` tag in the document at any given time (including dynamically added ones).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.click` and `.bind` don't have event delegation. You're executing them before the elements are loaded into the DOM. Either move your `.click` to below the anchors or add it inside a DOM ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        //do something..
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        //do something..
    });
});
```

Both of the above have the same result, use whichever you find more readable/maintainable.

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) works right now as it uses event delegation, which is, per a layman's view, similar to

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    //do something..
});
```

Note that `.live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+ so you should prefer the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for event delegation. Also note that `.on` only has the event delegation effect when bound to a parent element passing a descendants `selector` parameter.

Here's a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/HhFWG/) with [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

**edit:** As per OP's comment, since you're adding anchor tags dynamically, you have 2 options: event delegation (recommended) or re-binding the events every time you add new content.

In jQuery 1.7+, you should use `.on()` for event delegation:

```
$('#AnchorsDivID').on('click', 'a', function(){
    //do something..
});
```

Here's a full featured live demo with `.on` event delegation and Ajax:
[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/8hvLw/2/)

In jQuery <=1.6.4, you will have to use `.delegate()` or `.live()`. Which one provides better usability and performance for each version is shown at the [`.live()` jQuery API page](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

For jQuery >=1.4.3 <1.7:

```
$('#AnchorsDivID').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
    //do something..
});
```

Comment: What was happening: you were trying to bind a callback to an event of an element BEFORE the element was created. This solution solves that by binding the callback only after all the elements from the page are created.

Comment: @Bhoot give it a try now. `:)` If that doesn't work, show us some markup. This is virtually the only possible issue given your diagnosis (works with event delegation but not with event binding).

Comment: Also @Bhoot, are these anchor tags added dynamically or are they present when you load the page? If they are loaded dynamically, you should use the latter `.on()` method in my answer (possibly using a closer ancestor to those elements than `document`). Give a holler if you need extra help. `=]`

Comment: well the anchor tags are added dynamically to a div using ajax .. and i used .on() but it still is not working. one unusual thing i noticed now is that when i right click the browser and view source the div's content is blank(not containing the anchor tags) but the anchors tags are displayed by the browser.

Comment: @Bhoot That's problem then. Guess I'll write another paragraph. If you're using jQuery 1.7+, do `$('#AnchorDivID').on('click', 'a', function() {`. If you're using jQuery <=1.6, use either `.delegate` or `.live`. Alright, updated the answer.

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7.1 and the code is working now using .on() . Thanks it was very helpful and informative of you..

Comment: @Bhoot No problem man, just made a full featured fiddle with `.on` and ajax in the last couple minutes: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/8hvLw/1/), you're welcome. `:P`

Comment: @Bhoot Oh also, about the "unusual thing", there is nothing unusual there. View Source will show you the initial fetched markup of the page without any JS executed. In Chrome, you can easily see that it uses the [view-source URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source_URI_scheme). What you should use to view the dynamically added content is the DOM (which is the result of the rendered HTML and processed JS), not the source. Firebug has a nice DOM inspector, just as Chrome's Dev Tools. `=]` For Chrome/IE: Press F12, Firefox: install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and press F12.

Comment: And well, Firefox also has the right-click context menu "View Selection Source" when you select some HTML, this shows dynamic added markup as well. `=]`

Comment: i have firebug installed.but was unaware of this feature.thanks again for your valuable information. :)

Comment: Yes, Firebug has a nice HTML tab to browse the rendered DOM structure. `=]` Oh and obviously, the "Inspect Element with Firebug" right-click option is really handy to find elements in the DOM structure too.

Answer (score 0):

This code works absolutely fine with your html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('some action.');
    });
});
```

P.S. this code will run on all links!