# jQuery binding click event best practices

Tags: jquery

Lately when binding click events in jQuery I find myself questioning whether to use the jQuery shortcut `click()` or if I should specify the `.on('click', ...)` call myself.

The [.click().](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function in jQuery is just a shortcut.  To me it makes sense to use because jQuery handles everything behind the scenes accounting for the preferred method per the version of jQuery being used.  When I upgraded my scripts from jQuery 1.6 -> 1.7 I know that all of my `click()`s went from being a shortcut to `bind()` to the preferred `on()` method.  This, alone, seems reason enough to use the shortcuts.

*...however....*

Trevor Burnham, whom I greatly respect, says in his eBook [Async Javascript](http://leanpub.com/asyncjs) that he

> ... prefer(s) to consistently use the more powerful bind/on)   (over click)

That confuses me and I was wondering why using bind/on is 'more powerful'.

What have you found to be the best practices when binding events that have shortcuts in jQuery?  Use the shortcut or do it yourself?

Comment: I too would like to know what people think about this.

Comment: The author doesn't elaborate on his preference?

Comment: as far as I know (I'll let someone smarter submit an answer)  .on is used if the element has not been created yet , and click will work perfectly fine if the element is there when the page loads and always remains there

Comment: @Colin negative. The comment comes as he references how jQuery handles PubSub  - 'jQuery is publishing the link element's events to anyone who wants to subscribe'.  The book isn't about jQuery per se.

Comment: I don't believe he means it's 'more powerful' in the simple instance of binding a click handler, he just means it's more powerful overall.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**I think it has to do with personal preference and code readability more than anything.**

As far a more powerful goes `.on` lets you delegate events while shortcuts always operate on the element directly. For example `$('body').on('click', '.button', function(){});` will work for every `.button` element even those added after the fact with ajax or otherwise. While the shortcut cannot do this `$('.button').click(function(){});` is the only way to add a listener to `.button` and does not feature delegation, so `.button` elements added later will not have this binding.

Direct un-delegated events (like shortcuts) on multiple elements is also slightly less efficient then delegated events on a parent object. For example: lets say there are 15 `.button` elements on the page, `$('.button').click(...` will loop through all 15 elements and add an event listener to each; however `$('#parentElem').on('click', '.button', ...` will simply attach a single event listener to `#parentElem` that checks on the target, so one attach and one listener, vs a loop and 15 listeners.

And finally, `.on` has the advantage of allowing you to attach a function to an element from multiple events, which is not possible with shortcuts, for example: `$('.button').on('click mouseover keyup', ...` the function will trigger with click, mouseover or keyup!

---

Lets again say there are 15 `.button` elements in a div called `#parent`

Shortcut handler:

```
 $('.button').click(turnRed);
 $('.button').mouseover(turnRed);
 $('.button').keyup(turnRed);

 function turnRed(){
      $(this).css('color','red');
 }
```

- 4 jQuery objects created (yes I know you could cache it to 2 objects but this is an example)
- 3 element loops of 15 each, so jQuery hits elements here 45 times and attaches listeners
- 45 total event listeners
- future `.button` elements added to the scene do not `turnRed`

`.on` handler:

```
 $('#parent').on('click mouseover keyup', '.button', turnRed);

 function turnRed(){
      $(this).css('color','red');
 }
```

- 2 jQuery objects created
- No element loop, so jQuery hits elements once
- 3 total event listeners
- future `.button` elements add to the scene will in fact `turnRed`

Here `.on` clearly has the advantage

---

If your situation is simpler than this, then the advantage of `.on` may not make a difference to you, and the shortcut may be preferred as its more readable.

`$('#button').click(...` is nearly identical to `$('#button').on('click', ...` (see @Fabrício Matté's answer) and if we just want to add one listener to one event, the `.on`'s power is a moot point.

Personally because there are times when I want the advantage of `.on` I always use `.on` just to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the future delegation advantage of on() over click().  That helps me bridge the gap.  I was just messing around with it and created this...  http://jsfiddle.net/EkYgh/1/   I can see now that the resulting 'click this' divs only fire with on() and not click().

Comment: I'll +1 as you teared down that initial wall. `=]` Reading through your answer, I'd assume the author referred to `.on` as 'more powerful' because you can pass an events map to it. The event delegation part is slightly unrelated to the question, but I guess it counts as "powerful" seeing as it provides one more feature.

Comment: Groovy, @Joel love the jsfiddle great demo. With the number of questions I see here on overflow that are basically "I populated with ajax and now my events dont' work", I wish more people understood delegation.

Comment: I really thought this was unrelated to event delegation as the question doesn't include anything about it, but yeah, this is the main feature of `.on` so I understand how it'd fit. And @Fresheyeball, [I know that feel bro](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11386864/1331430).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté http://celebslife.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/keanu-reeves-whoa.jpg totalllly :)

Comment: Also @Joel I hope you don't mind if I [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/Jad6W/1/) your fiddle for future explanations. Excellent work man.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté of Course!  It was quick and dirty so I could see how it worked.  Anyone who includes pictures from the Matrix is free to fork anything of mine  ;)   Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a quick look at the [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) and see for yourself what your function call actually does.

Inside jQuery objects' `extend` (line 3754), jQuery iterates over all these method names at line 3909:

> blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick
>   mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave
>   change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu

Creating the shorthand methods which call the `.on` method for the given method without passing a selector attribute when those methods are invoked (line 3921):

```
this.on( name, null, data, fn )
```

Which just means it'll have **no event delegation** effect.

---

> What have you found to be the best practices when binding events that have shortcuts in jQuery? Use the shortcut or do it yourself?

The only difference between calling

```
$(selector).eventname(function(){...})
```

And

```
$(selector).on('eventname', function(){...})
```

Is that the shorthand method has the overhead of another function call (which is negligibly minimal).

**Update:** When making a custom build of jQuery with Grunt, the shorthand methods can be excluded with the `custom:-event-alias` parameter for an even smaller build ([Docs here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery)). Though, I personally tend to stick with the CDN builds.

---

As for how event delegation works and when it is preferred, check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) and [@Fresheyeball's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11552212/1331430).