# Switch between two css classes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to do something more efficiently in jQuery and that is switch a class to another class on click on `#trigger`.

So on odd clicks, class a ( `.a` ) will be given to all `<nav>`s in the document and then on even clicks, class a ( `.a` ) will be remove / switched-out and replaced with class b ( `.b` ).

The only way i could think about doing this is by adding the new class and removing the current class, but i'm sure there has to be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244392/jquery-toggle-state

Comment: You might find the aptly-named [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) helpful.

Comment: @DanielA.White Just what I described above. Adding and removing classes with .addClass() and .removeClass()

Comment: @Juhana Ah, thank you. it is aptly-named.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('.a').on('click',function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('a b');
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Why use .on('click'... instead of .click() ?

Comment: .click is just shorthand for .on('click' but the on method is more powerful. So I always just use .on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552174/jquery-binding-click-event-best-practices