# separated selector-event-(s) VS multiple if-statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `<button>` which each of them has its own duty on its `.on('click')`. Now I want to know, which algorithm is more standard | better | faster | optimize?

**Algorithm1:**

```
$("#btn1").click(function(e) { // do stuff for btn1 });
$("#btn2").click(function(e) { // do stuff for btn2 });
$("#btn3").click(function(e) { // do stuff for btn3 });
```

**Algorithm2:**

```
$("button").click(function(e) {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if     (id == '#btn1') { // do stuff for btn1 }
    elseif (id == '#btn2') { // do stuff for btn2 }
    elseif (id == '#btn2') { // do stuff for btn3 }

});
```

Comment: If there is any performance difference, it is negligible. It's a matter of personal preference and code organization. I prefer binding event to specific buttons (by ID). So I can clearly see which button does what. If there is a repeated code for multiple buttons, I create a function.

Comment: @VictorLevin you are right. tnx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery binding click event best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552174/jquery-binding-click-event-best-practices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely a matter of preference and personal style depending on the situation. I prefer to have work divided up into functions but if I did use the second example, I'd do it like this:

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    switch (this.id) {
    case 'btn1': // do stuff for btn1 
      break
    case 'btn2': // do stuff for btn2 
      break
    case 'btn3': // do stuff for btn3 
      break
    default: console.log(this.id, "has no behavior");
    }
});
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for your explanation. +1. Just one thing, why your answers are as *community wiki*? even what is that? Are you a moderator?

Comment: @stack: No, I just do it so that anyone can feel free to make improvements. I don't really care about the rep score.

Answer (score 1):

Querying the DOM by ID is much faster than tag name, so the first option should be faster. 
If speed is important, you could consider booting jQuery and do the same in vanilla js.

But in either case, for any real world usage the performance difference would be negligible.

Comment: If performance is truly a concern, jQuery would be the first to be eliminated (at least partially). +1